# Android + JSOUP get script information

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to parse the html page which contains:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> window._tim = {"user": "milk"}</script>
```

I have done  this:

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
```

And now  I  don't know how can I  get information - `{"user": "milk"}` using JSOUP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `doc.select("'head script")` to get all `script` elements.
Once you choose element, you need - you can get it's inner HTML using `html()` method.
Then you'll have to manually parse the JS to get required values.

Alternatively, you can use a `WebView` to run JS in it to get value of `window._tim` directly

Comment: When I did - Elements metaElements = doc.select("head script"); I saw only  some part of scripts but  not all.

Comment: @Delphian, that's a `toString()` method cutting part of code. use `Element.html()` method to get full code

Comment: I  am using  Elements metaElements = doc.select("head script"); String name = metaElements.html(); but saw only some part of  scripts

Comment: @Delphian, you need firstly to get some exact `Element` from `Elements`. Like `Element element = metaElements.get(0); element.html();` `Elements` is actually a `List` of `Element`

Comment: Vlad, thank you! I changed the request from head script to body script and found everithing  what i need!

Comment: @Delphian, I just thought that all scripts should stay inside `<head>` tag.

Comment: Vlad, can I ask one more  question? Can I click on button (which is located on the site) using JSOUP?

Comment: @Delphian, no, you can't. But you can perform same actions that are done on button click. Like sending a request. If you specify the site, and the button, I can help you with it

Comment: @ Vlad Matvienko can you give me a email? I  send the link and information about button. Thank you for your time!